# image not showing in Foundation Reveal Modal

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation 4 framework. I want to show a modal in my interface:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <h2>Congratulations, you just earnt the</h2>
    <p class="lead">VCA Basic Security Badge</p>
    <img scr="../images/templating.png" />
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>
```

When a link is clicked, the modal shows up, but the problem is that the image within the modal is not showing. There is even no broken link icon.

Anyone familiar with this problem in Foundation 4 Reveal component?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but, to those that are still looking, you need to have "data-reveal" in your div.

`<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   ...
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: should be src not scr

Comment: Hi Jennifer, thanks, but that wasn't the issue, my actual code is in haml, where I corrected the src typo, but because more people are familiar with html, I showed the html expample (which still has the src typo

Answer (score 0):

Besides the scr/src typo I cannot see anything inherently wrong with your HTML and Foundation 4.3.2. I even copied your code to this [codepen](http://codepen.io/adam-huffman/full/15b011b8c34ea244d70c3abf51796a6b) and made some scenarios to recreate what you describe.

Replace `<img scr="../images/templating.png" />` with `<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">` the modal displays an image. Notice I changed **scr** to **src** and give the source a working path.

Replace `<img scr="../images/templating.png" />` with `<img src="../images/templating.png">` the  broken image icon shows. Notice I changed **scr** to **src** but did not give the source a working path.

Replace `<img scr="../images/templating.png" />` with `<img scr="http://placehold.it/350x150">` no image or broken image icon shows.. Notice I kept **scr** to and gave it a working path.

Since you stated that the image does not show and you do not see a broken link/image icon I can only guess that there is something wrong with your HTML syntax either close to your image tag or your image tag itself.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for looking into this. I posted this issue some time ago. In the meantime I stopped using Foundation as a front end framework. I'm using Bourbon Neat now.